# How to find out programmatically whether a terminal supports UTF8?

Tags: node.js, utf-8, terminal, command-line-interface

I'm writing a CLI using Node.js, and I would like to use some UTF-8 characters. However, not all terminals support UTF-8, and instead the output looks quite crappy.

So, the simple question is: Is there a simple way to programmatically figure out whether a terminal supports UTF-8?

Comment: 'echo $LC_CTYPE' or 'chcp' on Windows outputs information about terminal encoding, you could probably run those inside Node and parse the output.

Comment: echo $LC_CTYPE does nothing on my terminal (zsh on macOS). So while this may work on some systems, it does not seem to be a reliable way of detecting this. Thanks anyway 

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. However, you can set the encoding to UTF-8 with this:

```
process.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');

process.stderr.setEncoding('utf8');
```